# Apply SidebarListStyle() to Mac only

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mac-catalyst

In my Catalyst project I'd like to apply `SidebarListStyle()` to Mac only.

My problem is I can't build the project, even when I check for OS. Heres an example:

```
struct CrossList: View {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Mac Test")
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
    #else
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("iOS Test")
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```

This gives me the following error when building:

> 'SidebarListStyle' is unavailable in iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac Catalyst *is* essentially iOS – just running on a Mac. `SidebarListStyle` is only available when developing a full-on macOS (non-Catalyst) app, and would be contained in the compiler directive `#if os(macOS)` like this:

```
struct CrossList: View {
    #if os(macOS)
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Mac Test")
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
    #else
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("iOS Test")
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your content is more complex than this, then this doesn't scale. Instead, consider eschewing the auto-return part of swift and generate the same thing via:

```swift
var body: some View {
    var listView = List {
        Text(text)
    }

    #if os(macOS)
        listView = listView.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    #endif

    return listView
}

private var text: String {
    #if os(macOS)
        return "Mac Test"
    #else
        return "iOS Test"
    #endif
}
```

Here I'm setting up the shared, common code for both platforms, then conditionally adding things in a platform check. You can also see in the shared code that i extracted out platform specific values into dedicated private `var`s so I can switch there locally without muddying the view creation callsite.

I have found this to work better where you have remarkably similar code except for differing values and where slight additions need to be made per platform.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it :

```
struct StyledSidebar<Sidebar: View>: View {
    let sidebar: Sidebar

    #if os(macOS)
    var body: some View {
        self.sidebar
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
    #else
    var body: some View {
        self.sidebar
    }
    #endif
}
```

And simply call :

```
StyledSidebar(sidebar: MyList())
```